# How to handle object freezing for redux

Tags: json, object, redux, freeze

Regarding redux -> in development mode I would like to "freeze" the object state after the reducers have done their work and before subscribers get notified...

My approach was to define middleware for "freezing" the state of the object (e.g. with node module deep-freeze-strict).

But it seems this is not the correct approach. Because of a subscriber receives the updated state before the freezing takes place...

Does anybody has an idea how to define such freezing before the subscribers are notified??

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this was to define a function which wraps the reducers:

```
export function freezeStateOfReducer(reducer): any {
  return (state, action) => {

    let newState = reducer(state, action);

    freezeState(newState);

    return newState;

  };
}

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  firstReducer: ...
});

createStore(freezeStateOfReducer(rootReducer));
```

Comment: if `freezeState` is a simple util like `Object.freeze` then it only freezes the top object. is your's recursive?

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting question, actually.  In *theory*, the only state updates should be happening in the reducer.  In practice, I've definitely seen cases where people were accidentally mutating things in their `mapState` functions.  You're definitely right that subscribers are notified before the middleware sees the updated state.

This *might* be a valid use case for a store enhancer, which could ensure that the state is frozen before actually notifying subscribers.  Or, a higher-order reducer that wraps around your normal root reducer.

Also, there are several existing "freeze state in development" utilities already out there.  See the [DevTools#Linting](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/devtools.md#linting) section of my [Redux addons catalog](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links) for a list of those existing libs.